# VBA/PowerPoint: Split date-time field into lines

Tags: vba, text, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation, where I add an automatically updating date-time field to a text box (via Insert -> Text -> Date & Time, with checked "Update Automatically"). The textbox is resized so that the text (Wednesday, March 31, 2021) is split across two lines, for example:

```
  Wednesday,
March 31, 2021
```

I would like to process the information line-wise, trying the following VBA:

```
Sub TryLines()
    For Each Line In ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Lines
        Debug.Print Line
    Next Line
End Sub
```

If I call this function with the whole date-time field (distributed across two lines) selected, I get the following output:

```
Wednesday, March 31, 2021
Wednesday, March 31, 2021
```

I.e. PowerPoint recognizes that there are actually two lines, but is apparently not able to "break up" the date-time field into actual separate lines, and instead treats the date-time field as a monolith. A similar thing seems to happen for `Characters`.

**Actual question:** Is there a way to retrieve the text *within a field* line-wise? I would like to be independent of date format and of the actual wrapping.

Some more background, if helpful: At last, I would like to compute the polygon formed by the text-selection highlightning. Since I did not find a method to do this in `TextRange2`, I thought about splitting into lines and compute rectangles per line:

```
Sub TryToComputeLineBounds() ' call this while the date-time field is selected
    For Each Line In ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Lines
        Dim x(4) As Single, y(4) As Single
        Line.RotatedBounds x(1), y(1), x(2), y(2), x(3), y(3), x(4), y(4)
        Debug.Print Line
        For i = 1 To 4
            Debug.Print x(i) & " | "; y(i)
        Next i
    Next Line
End Sub
```

I realized that the measured points are the same per (what I assumed) line, and then found out that `Lines` does not actually give me the lines within a date-time field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the Lines and Characters as a monolith because there is something special about inserted Date & Time that means it will never "break up".  I tried your code with a text box that had some characters I typed in and it worked - I was able to read lines and characters one at a time.

So maybe make a temporary copy of the text box but without automatic date inserted, i.e. a Text value equivalent to the date, then use the copy to compute the polygon.

Comment: I know that my code works on normal text. Nonetheless, your idea is interesting - however it would require to basically carry over all formatting to the copy.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see another way to measure your polygon with text wrapping unless Character.RotatedBounds is working correctly.  You need to use it to get the width of each character regardless of typeface calculated by x(2) - x(1).  To check for the line text wrapping, check each character and have a running total of widths for each character and when it is more than the width of the textbox you will know the text has wrapped.  When moving down to the next line you may have to take into account the maximum height of characters on that line, the heights calculated with y(3) - y(2).

Answer (score 0):

As Morboss surmised, a date field is read as one line regardless of how it appears. In the user interface, if you click on a multiline text, the insertion point appears where you click. Not so with a date: the first time you click on it the entire field is selected and no insertion point appears.

As a workaround, get the day name and date with string parsing:

```
Sub GetDayName()
    Dim SpacePos As Long
    Dim FieldText As String, DayName As String, DateValue As String
    
    FieldText = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Text
    SpacePos = InStr(FieldText, " ")
    DayName = Left(FieldText, SpacePos)
    DateValue = Right(FieldText, (Len(FieldText) - SpacePos))
    MsgBox DayName
    MsgBox DateValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. And apologies - I should have been more clear: The wrapping position is not fixes (neither is the date format). Moreover, string manipulation will probably not help me in actually measuring the text. (Or will it?)

Comment: Your original post was about separating the parts of the date field. Text measurements will change with every typeface.